# Duda sobre integracion PayPal

Tags: html, paypal

estoy intentado añadir el botón de PayPal a un html para realizar un único pago. Esto es a modo de prueba para ir familiarizándome con la integración. Para ello lo hago utlizando **Smart buttons** desde el siguiente [link](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/) Solo hice la configuración básica como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y copié el código quedando mi `html` así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejercicio de Prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
      function initPayPalButton() {
        paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'paypal',

          },

          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{"description":"Ejemplo de botón","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":1}}]
            });
          },

          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

              // Full available details
              console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

              // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
              const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
              element.innerHTML = '';
              element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

              // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');

            });
          },

          onError: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      }
      initPayPalButton();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahora, al momento de tratar de querer pagar iniciando sesión con mi cuenta me dice que el login es inválido. Lo cual es raro porque si inicio sesión de manera aparte los datos están correctos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay algo que se deba hacer aparte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que intentas iniciar con tu cuenta paypal en una versión sandbox, debes crear una cuenta en:

https://sandbox.paypal.com/

y con esas haces tus pruebas, si deseas hacerlo con plata de verdad debes cambiar la url por paypal.com sin el sandbox.

Comment: Uy que bobo, no vi semejante obviedad, mil gracias genio